# How to import module according platform

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want import a module according platform.

For example:

```
import MapViewIOS from 'react-native-map-clustering'
import MapViewAndroid from 'react-native-maps'

const MapView = Platform.select({
  ios: MapViewIOS,
  android: MapViewAndroid,
})
```

Error:

> JSX element type 'MapView' does not have any construct or call
> signatures.ts(2604)

Comment: Try In JSX make a condition for platform.os === "iOS"? <MapViewIos />: <MapViewAndroid/>

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine.

Here is an [abstracted example](https://snack.expo.io/@tnr_c/platformspecificcomponent) of what you are trying to do working.

Which suggests you are using MapView incorrectly or the version of MapView you are using is broken.

Answer (score 0):

In react-native you should separate the file by platform. For example, Create two files with `MapView.ios.js` and `MapView.android.js` name so export specific component for platform and anywhere you need to use MapView import them like this `import MapView from "./MapView"`